# Put all credential to file .json

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, nodemailer

i am new at Javascript, and i still confuse about javascript and using json file. I working at one of my office project about sending a message, i have been complete all the code at back-end and front-end, but when the code was review with my project leader, he say to put all the credential to file json. To send a message / mail, i using nodemailer from node.js

Here is the credential i have to put in json file

```
const transporter = mail.createTransport({ //unresolved
  service: 'Gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  auth: {
    user: 'no.replyxx@xx.org',
    pass: 'xxxxxx'
  }
});
```

I have put it into the json file, but when i call it at my javascript file, i don't know how to call it, i try to import a json file, but i just get bug for it can someone help me, precisely my question is how i write a credential to json file and how i use it at my javascript? Thanks

Comment: A common and secure way of dealing with this is to use a `.env` file and read into the node environment. A popular library for this is [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First thing, in [JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON), there is no `const`. `const` comes from JS. If you want to save your credentials to a JSON file, it will contain something like this:

```
{
  "service": "Gmail",
  "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
  "auth": {
    "user": "no.replyxx@xx.org",
    "pass": "xxxxx"
  }
}
```

also, it needs double quotes and not single quotes.

After this all you need to do is require it

```
const credentials = require('./jsonCredentials.json');
```

Answer (score 3):

You should look into using [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

You can use it like so

```js
// this will find the .env file at the root of your project
// and parse the entries into key/value pairs on the `process.env` object
require('dotenv').config()

const transporter = mail.createTransport({ //unresolved
  service: 'Gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  auth: {
    user: process.env.MAIL_USER,
    pass: process.env.MAIL_PASS
  }
});
```

Create a `.env` file at the root of your project

```
// .env

MAIL_USER=no.replyxx@xx.org
MAIL_PASS=secret-password
```

Also, you should ensure that this does not get committed to your version control system.
If you're using git, create a `.gitignore` and make sure you have an entry for `.env`

```
// .gitignore

.env
```

Comment: This would be my suggestion as well. Also works great as a pattern for hiding API Keys and whatnot

Comment: Where i should save .env file? If i want to create one?

Comment: Thankyou for suggestion @dillon, my problem has been resolved, i will learn about .env

Comment: @MarvinPaulus .env is usually on the root of the project, i.e. the same level as package.json

Answer (score 1):

First, you can import the content of a file using the `fs` library method called `fs.readFileSync(filePath)`.

Then, you parse the content into a JSON object using the `JSON.parse(content)` method.

From there, you can have the JSON content as an object, and you can now use it in your `createTransport` method call.

Comment: Can you recomend me any link as references? I don't know about fs library

Comment: FS readFileSync:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfilesync_path_options


JSON parse:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: Also, as others have mentioned, using the env will be better. You can lookup on the dotenv library to inject the `.env` file into the `process.env` object. See the following for documentations https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv

Comment: Thankyou @Yee Hui Poh, my problem has been solved, with a little different ways, i will learn about fs library may it can usefull for my next project. thank you

Answer (score 1):

I just want to add that I recommend using .env files which are more secure.

But to answer your question,
Since I'm assuming you're using ReactJS, you can do something like this:

config.js

```
export default const config = {
  service: 'Gmail',
  host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
  auth: {
    user: 'no.replyxx@xx.org',
    pass: 'xxxxxx'
  }
}
```

Then simply import to use it

```
import config from './config.js'

function myFunction()
{
  const transporter = mail.createTransport(config);
}
```

Comment: you can't write `const` in JSON file. You just put JS data into a file with .json.

Comment: So, i should add export default code above json file?

Comment: Thanks for that @illiteratewriter, I have updated it.

Comment: @illiteratewriter, i done put all the JS data into file .json, but how i can use that data to my js file, which at my js file, there is a code for connecting a nodemailer service?

Comment: You will need to import it. Just like the second code block above.

Comment: So, i have to export json file and then i can import at my javascript file?

Comment: Ok thankyou @polcats and my problem has resolved, but a little bit different ways. Thankyou very much

Comment: And @illiteratewriter thankyou too, my problem has been resolved